# How To Make Multiple Themes Change Based On Which Toggle Switch Is Turned On

Tags: java, android, android-togglebutton

I am attempting to create a theme preference page for my app.  I have been able to get one toggle switch to work. The theme changes when I turn it on and off.  I would like to have multiple different themes that can be switch when one of the other toggle switches are selected.  I have done a fairly extensive search for any samples of how this would be accomplished, but cannot seem to find anything.

I would appreciate any guidance on this subject.  Below is a screenshot of of the theme color Banana selected, when I apply the onyx them the toggle for banana does not turn off and in order to get back to my default them I have to turn off both onyx and banana.

Here is my SettingsActivity where I am applying the theme

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String PREFS_NAME = "prefs";
private static final String PREF_BANANA_THEME = "banana_theme";
private static final String PREF_ONYX_THEME = "onyx_theme";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the chosen theme
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences( PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE );
    boolean useBananaTheme = preferences.getBoolean( PREF_BANANA_THEME, false );
    if (useBananaTheme) {
        setTheme( R.style.AppTheme_Banana_NoActionBar );
    }
    boolean useOnyxTheme = preferences.getBoolean( PREF_ONYX_THEME, false );
    if (useOnyxTheme) {
        setTheme( R.style.AppTheme_Onyx_NoActionBar );
    }
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_settings );
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById( R.id.toolbar );
    setSupportActionBar( toolbar );
    Objects.requireNonNull( getSupportActionBar() ).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    });
    Switch toggle1 = (Switch) findViewById( R.id.switch1 );
    toggle1.setChecked( useBananaTheme );
    toggle1.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
            toggleThemeBanana( isChecked );
        }
    } );
    Switch toggle2 = (Switch) findViewById( R.id.switch2 );
    toggle2.setChecked( useOnyxTheme );
    toggle2.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
            toggleThemeOnyx( isChecked );
        }
    } );
}
private void toggleThemeBanana(boolean bananaTheme) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences( PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE ).edit();
    editor.putBoolean( PREF_BANANA_THEME, bananaTheme );
    editor.apply();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity( intent );
}
private void toggleThemeOnyx(boolean onyxTheme) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences( PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE ).edit();
        editor.putBoolean( PREF_ONYX_THEME, onyxTheme );
        editor.apply();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity( intent );
    }
}
```

[image] [image]

Comment: I have updated the code above, I have been able to make the theme change based on which toggle switch is turned on.  I need some assistance with turning off the previously used theme switch. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out this problem.  I needed to set all the toggle switches to false. Below is a snippet of code showing an example of this.

```
final Switch blue = (Switch) findViewById( R.id.blue );
        blue.setChecked( useBlueTheme );
        blue.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
                toggleThemeBlue(isChecked);
                //toggleThemeBlue(false);
                toggleThemeGreen(false);
                toggleThemeOrange(false);
                toggleThemeRed(false);
                toggleThemeYellow(false);
            }
        } );
        final Switch green = (Switch) findViewById( R.id.green );
        green.setChecked( useGreenTheme );
        green.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
                toggleThemeGreen(isChecked);
                toggleThemeBlue(false);
                //toggleThemeGreen(false);
                toggleThemeOrange(false);
                toggleThemeRed(false);
                toggleThemeYellow(false);
            }

        } );
```

I hope this will help someone else who might be looking for something similar.